# Is there a microformat for labeling sentences, words, parts-of-speech, etc

Tags: nlp, microformats, part-of-speech

Is there a microformat for basic natural language process that has tags for sentences, words, parts-of-speech, etc...? I have searched the web but could not find any.

Comment: Standard HTML tags cover some of this. Do you have an example of something that is not covered?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What kinds of programs would read this info and what would you like for them to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are looking for is the "CreativeWork" schema, specifically the "Article" specific type of schema.org

http://www.schema.org/CreativeWork

http://www.schema.org/Article